# How to stop Spring batch job when error in processor

Tags: spring, spring-batch

In my batch job, I have a single step with reading from Database , processing the record and writing back the same record to same table.(ie updating record with processed values or error reason if processing failed).

I am using AsyncItemProcessor for multi thread processing. When I get error in ItemProcessor.process() method, I throw an exception and batch job ends with FAILED status. This failed status is a requirement.

Because, its AsyncItemProcessor, I am unable to access ItemProcessListener.onProcessError().

How do I write the errorMessage to Item Table when there is an error ?

Answer (score 0):

This is a known limitation of using the `AsyncItemProcessor` which is mentioned in its [Javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/api/org/springframework/batch/integration/async/AsyncItemProcessor.html):

```
While not an exhaustive list, things like StepExecution.filterCount will not     
reflect the number of filtered items and 
ItemProcessListener.onProcessError(Object, Exception) will not be called.
```

There is an [open issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/issues/833) to update the reference documentation as well.

> How do I write the errorMessage to Item Table when there is an error ?

The `AsyncItemProcessor` submits a `FutureTask` to the task executor and the only way to know if an exception happened in the task is by unwrapping the future (the exception will be actually wrapped in a `java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException` when the `FutureTask.get` is called). Now since [the future is unwrapped in the `AsyncItemWriter`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/d8fc58338d3b059b67b5f777adc132d2564d7402/spring-batch-integration/src/main/java/org/springframework/batch/integration/async/AsyncItemWriter.java#L64-L82), you can use an `ItemWriteListener` and react to processing errors. You can find a complete example [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/pull/366#issuecomment-436929835).